# ASP.NET: Add tree node at specific level everytime

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview on a page, i want to update/add nodes to it on some events -
eg., I have a dropdown list, i have checkbox list, etc.
Treeview has a node at level 0 already defined.
I want to add ONLY one node as a child of node 0 on dropdown_selectedIndexchanged event.
for that I am doing this -

The treeview on aspx page

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tv1" runat="server">
   <Nodes>
       <asp:TreeNode Text="parent" Value="" ShowCheckBox="False"></asp:TreeNode>
   </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

code on .cs page

```
dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tv1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(dropdown.SelectedIndex.Text.Trim)));
}
```

I see the problem but not sure how to solve it.
The problem is - I want to add ONE and ONLY ONE child node at level 0 of tv1 treeview.

how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

It might not be working because of "AutoPostBack" property of dropdown is set to false. The event handler will fire only if you have set this property to true. Following code is working for me.

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TreeView ID="tv1" runat="server">
   <Nodes>

       <asp:TreeNode Text="parent" Value="" ShowCheckBox="False"></asp:TreeNode>
   </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Code Behind (You can get value directly or by index):

```
        protected void dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tv1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Clear();
            tv1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(dropdown.SelectedValue));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but would t this code will be executed every time this event is fired, I only want one and oy one child node at node[0]

Comment: you can use some javascript or jqeury to do it on the client side, which is one option to avoid server round trip, but depends upon your scenario if you wanting to save the values, then server side logic is easier to implement. [Edit Code Behind] you can clear child nodes before adding